# how to pipe event in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, events

From reading this: [bash event-designators](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators) , I can make e.g. `!?commandString`. So I did:

```
$find somedir -iregex '.*Makefile.*'
$bla/bla/Makefile
$bla/bla/bla/Makefile
$...
```

and now, I would like to use it with the event-desginator to pipe it:

```
$!?nameOfFile | sed -n 'p1' | xargs cd
```

err:

```
bash: !?Makefile | sed -n '1p': event not found
```

it takes whole line as event, so How can i make the `end` of the event in order to further processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the linked manual:

> The trailing ‘?’ may be omitted if the string is followed immediately
>   by a newline.

Since in the string is *not* followed immediately by a newline, it should have a trailing `?`:

```
!?nameOfFile? | sed -n 'p1' | xargs cd
```

Though that won't help you, since `xargs cd`  will run `cd` in a separate process, so your shell won't be affected. You'd need something like:

```
cd "$(!?nameOfFile? | head -n1)"
```